# Positing Labels around on buffers around a centroid

Tags: qgis

I'm using Qgis 2.16.2, I am having an issue positioning labels around a centroid.
To help you to built a mental picture of what i am doing: I have a centroid point with 400 metre buffers so 400, 800, 1200 etc.. I am trying to label each buffer with corresponding values

The issue i have is that whenever i create labels they default to being horizontal (next to each other) along the buffers, which is great but i want  them to be vertical (above each other) mainly for composer purposes. 
Is there anyway i can change the positioning of the labels without manually moving them and just using the Label positioning tools? or at least a way that when i manually move them to ensure they are all perfectly lined up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean: Under layer properties for each buffer go to 'placement' and set the quadrant to top centre and offset the y axis by the buffer amount

[image]

**EDIT:**

So to do this using the Multi-Buffer plugin is exactly the same but instead you use the rule-based labelling:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the Reply :), The advice helps in labelling the buffers but my issue is that all my buffers are on one layer due to me using the Multi Ring buffer plugin. The way you have done it is definatley something i can try but if i can find a way to do it with the multi ring buffer and labels that would be great.
Just in case i wasnt specific enough about what i was doing here is a image of the issue im facing http://imgur.com/a/NDE0B (FYI: Ive been trying to move labels using co-ordinates)

Comment: No worries. I've edited my answer. I used the multi buffer plugin and all seems to work how you want it.  I wouldn't use coordinates to places labels as you can start having issue when you zoom in and out (unless all your layers are working off map units, then you won't have any scaling issues).

Comment: Yeah thank you man, I just tried your second way out and that's exactly what i'm after!!! That's a massive help and i can carry on with this project now! Again thank you so much! Yeah i work strictly in map units so co-ords aren't an issue :)